# how to align HTML Table filters to left

Tags: html

is it possible to align the buttons to the left in a single column of the table.

```
<p>Perform actions and retrieve information from the grid by using public methods</p>
<div class="tf_tools">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Check if it has grid" onclick="alert( tf_table8.HasGrid() );" />
                <input type="button" value="Filter table" onclick="tf_table8.Filter();" />
                <input type="button" value="Clear grid" onclick="tf_table8.ClearFilters(); tf_table8.Filter();" />
                <input type="button" value="Remove grid" onclick="tf_table8.RemoveGrid();" />
                <input type="button" value="Reset filter grid" onclick="tf_table8.AddGrid();" />
                <input type="button" value="Get starting row index" onclick="alert( tf_table8.GetStartRowIndex() );" />
                <input type="button" value="Get last row index" onclick="alert( tf_table8.GetLastRowIndex() );" />
                <input type="button" value="Get valid rows index" onclick="alert( tf_table8.GetValidRowsIndex() );" />
                <input type="button" value="Get filters ids" onclick="alert( tf_table8.GetFiltersId() );" />
                <input type="button" value="Get filter value col 2" onclick="alert( tf_table8.GetFilterValue(2) ); " />
                <input type="button" value="Set filter value col 2" onclick="tf_table8.SetFilterValue(2,'keyword here');" />
                <input type="button" value="Return column 0 values" onclick="alert( tf_table8.GetColValues(0,false) );" />
                <input type="button" value="Return table data" onclick="alert( tf_table8.GetTableData() );" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<table id="table8" class="mytable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th>World Regions</th>
        <th>Population ( 2007 Est.)</th>
        <th>Population % of World</th>
        <th>% Population ( Penetration )</th>
        <th>Usage % of World</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Africa</td>
        <td>933,448,292</td>
        <td>14.2 %</td>
        <td>3.5 %</td>
        <td>3.0 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Asia</td>
        <td>3,712,527,624</td>
        <td>56.5 %</td>
        <td>10.5 %</td>
        <td>35.6 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Europe</td>
        <td>809,624,686</td>
        <td>12.3 %</td>
        <td>38.6 %</td>
        <td>28.6 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Middle East</td>
        <td>193,452,727</td>
        <td>2.9 %</td>
        <td>10.0 %</td>
        <td>1.8 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>North America</td>
        <td>334,538,018</td>
        <td>5.1 %</td>
        <td>69.4 %</td>
        <td>21.2 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Latin America / Caribbean</td>
        <td>556,606,627</td>
        <td>8.5 %</td>
        <td>16.0 %</td>
        <td>8.1 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Oceania / Australia</td>
        <td>34,468,443</td>
        <td>0.5 %</td>
        <td>53.5 %</td>
        <td>1.7 %</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

var table8_Props = {
    col_0: "select",
    public_methods: true
};
var tf8 = setFilterGrid("table8", table8_Props);

http://jsfiddle.net/koalyptus/bYs5U/embedded/result/

Comment: This question is not very clear. What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

try to use  `<br />` after every `<button>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table with 2 columns. In your 1st column would be your table. the 2nd column would be your buttons.